# How to close the pop up which is in div tag using jquery on button click

Tags: jquery

Below is my pop up code with close button i need to close the pop up on clicking the close button image how can i do this

```
<div id="divHeader" class="NewPopHead">
                        Change Password <a style="margin-top:18px; margin-right:15px; float:right; " class="img Close" id="closebutton"></a>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Hi Karal. Please take a moment to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54033250/edit) and add your own attempts. We'd love to help you fix your code for closing the popup, however you haven't provided any.

Comment: Your <a> tag doesn't have any text inside

Comment: Learn to use the correct element where necessary. Your <a> is not correctly used. I suggested you change to <span>. Also, both <a> and <span> are inline elements and would only show up if you have content in them or there are declared as block elements witb defined width and  height.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jQuery.
`$("#closebutton").on("click", function(e) { $("YOUR POP UP DIV").hide() })`

Comment: I had already tried this   $("#closebutton").on("click", function (e) {
        debugger;
        $("divHeader").hide()
    }) but its not working

Comment: it should be `$("#divHeader")` instead of `$("divHeader")`, you are missing a hash. Check out jQuery selector first if you are not familiar with targeting class or id.

Comment: Also, you should paste HTML code here as well. Otherwise, people will not understand your question comprehensively.

Answer (score 0):

## Edited

Target the parent element of the close button and hide using jquery hide method.

```
$("#closebutton").on("click", function(e) { $(this).parent().hide() })
```

Comment: I am getting this error Uncaught TypeError: e.parent is not a function

Comment: I have edited the answer, it should be $(this).parent().hide()

Comment: still i am facing same issue as VM1635:1 Uncaught TypeError: e.parent is not a function

Comment: the pop up is getting hided but after closing the pop up background screen is getting faded which is not allowing the user to do any operations